# Access a variable in Matlab using strcat

Tags: string, matlab

I have a situation where I want have many temperatures placed in column vectors, for example T101, T102, … and I would like to access these using a string cat command and place them in another vector. I created a simplified example to show what I am trying to achieve.

```
    clc
clear all
T102 = [5; 8; 20; 21];
P102 = [T102;1]
P102 = [strcat('T','102');1]
```

However, I am receiving an error for the second time I define P102 because it has now become the string 'T102' and I want it to become the variable T102 and not the string.

Comment: Is the usage of these variables absolutely required? Because using a 2-D array would be a much better path forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to do and if it’s the right way.
But to answer your question you should use `eval`:

```
P102 = [eval(strcat('T','102'));1];
```